# Unknown plant in garden

Tags: identification

What is this large plant? It sprouted up in Alberta Canada without been manually planted.[image: Unknown plant]

Google Lens identifies it as Populus lasiocarpa. However, it must be wrong - according to wikipiedia, Populus lasiocarpa is native to China.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the ID is close; I would have said cottonwood  or Balsam Popular, at least something in the popular/ cottonwood category. They will readily seed themselves. You may have a neighbor that has planted a lasiocarpa and it is now mature enough to produce seed. In some locations with warmer climate ( IL ), it is illegal to plant cotton wood as a  landscaping tree.

Comment: Good to know that in some locations it is illegal to plant cotton wood as a landscaping tree. I am going to get rid of this plant from my garden. Thanks a lot.